# Formatting Shortcode to Display in Visual Mode

Tags: php, shortcode

I was wondering if it's possible to convert this kind of shortcode:

```
[card name="Muscle Band" set="XY" no="121" c="name"][/card]
```

Into this in Visual Mode (in blue-colored text):

> Muscle Band XY 121

Basically, something that detects shortcode that's in the above format and changes it into the second format only when you look at it in Visual mode (the card name, set, and number).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use shortcake ui for this. 
[Shortcake in the repository][1]

[1]: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-ui/ shortcake ui plugin

Answer (score 0):

Yes it certainly is. To convert your shortcode visually in editor you must do the following:

1. Add a filter on `mce_external_plugins`
2. Add your *tinymce* plugin script url to the `$plugin_array` and return it
3. In your `tinymce.PluginManager.add` function respond to editor events *BeforeSetContent* and *GetContent*
4. In your *BeforeSetContent* javascript callable function, execute the code that replaces your shortcode with a visual one
5. In your *GetContent* javascript callable function, execute the code that restores your shortcode from its visual format.

I know this sounds complicated. But as usual, it's simple once you analyze it. [Here's a tutorial](https://generatewp.com/take-shortcodes-ultimate-level/) that takes you through the motions. You can also download a [sample code](https://github.com/bainternet/bs3_panel_shortcode) from github that will get your started

Tip: Your visual component, ie: a paragraph tag, should contain a unique data attribute `<p data-my-shortcode-name="my_shortcode_data_is_stored_here"`. This allows for a successful restore-to-text operation.